# How do I check if an image field is empty in a template file?

Tags: 8

I am trying to check if the user_picture field is empty using the twig template, but I am not able to do this.

I tried lots of ways:-

```
{% if node.user_picture.value %}
{% if node.user_picture.entity %}
{% if content.user_picture.value %}
{% if content.user_picture|render.entity %}
{% if content.user_picture|render %}
```

---

Sample of code:

```
  {% if node.user_picture.value %}
    <p>User-picture 02</p>
    {{ user_picture }}
  {% else %}
    <p>Anymonus-picture 02</p>
    <div>
      <a href="#"><img src="{{base_path}}/WEBSITE/themes/THEME/images/anonymous.jpg" alt=""></a>
    </div>
  {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 10):

Use the method [isEmpty()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21TypedData%21Plugin%21DataType%21ItemList.php/function/ItemList%3A%3AisEmpty/8.4.x) on the image field:

```
  {% if node.field_image.isempty %}
    <p>Field "field_image" is empty.</p>
  {% endif %}
```

Although in this case you might need to check the user entity of the node author:

```
  {% if node.uid.entity.user_picture.isempty %}
    <p>Picture of the node author is empty.</p>
  {% endif %}
```

Comment: I tried it, but it's not working, Its always outputting FALSE

Comment: I also tried {{ node.user_picture.isempty }} and it is not rendering anything

Comment: Are you sure you have this field in the node? This is a field name used in the user entity, see the second example.

Comment: Yes, I am sure, I am trying to overwrite the comment.html.twig file, to be able to give the comment a user image even if the user has not added any image yet (Default image). and i did try the second example and still not working.

Comment: The code examples in the question suggested it is a node template, because a comment template has no `node` variable. So for a comment template you have to replace `node.` with `comment.`

Comment: Remember: use `node.field_image` not `content.field_image`. I may have lost some hair over this ;)

Comment: As well you can check if it is not empty by `{% if node.field_file is not empty %}`

Answer (score 3):

I was able to use either one of the following in a template. The key to all of this is that you use `node.user_picture`.

```
{% if node.user_picture is empty %}
{% if node.user_picture.isEmpty() %}
{% if node.user_picture.isEmpty %}
```

That can be used to verify the field is empty. If you have set a default image on the content type field's setting, then you can use `content.user_picture` which should display either the image that was selected on the entity or the default image from the field's image setting.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it best to use Drupal to set a default image for users. Edit the User Picture field and upload a default image.

If you're in comment.html.twig, "user_picture" is available just as "node" or "content" is:

```
{{ user_picture }}
```

And the way to the image value is:

```
{{ user_picture['#user'].user_picture.entity.uri.0.value }}
```

That's if you did a full install of Drupal and not a minimal install. In a minimal install you will need to add your own field to the User Account fields. Then you just access your field name:

```
{{ user_picture['#user'].field_machine_name.entity.uri.0.value }}
```

What I've done before in the comment.html.twig file:

```
{% if user_picture['#user'].user_picture.entity.uri.0.value != "" %}
    <a href="/user/{{ user_picture['#user'].uid.0.value }}">
         <img src="{{ file_url(user_picture['#user'].user_picture.entity.uri.0.value) }}" />
    </a>
{% else %}
    <img src="/path/to/image" />
{% endif %}
```

Also you can check for a user id:

```
{% if user_picture['#user'].uid.0.value > 0 %}
```

A good way to set a picture for anonymous users.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to negate the twig condition for others purposes :

```
{% if not node.field_image.isempty %}
  <p>Field "field_image" is not empty.</p>
{% endif %}
```